# setting M2_repo classpath variable correctly for mapsforge project

Tags: android, eclipse, openstreetmap

I have been trying to run some of the applications provided by the mapsforge project. I followed the instructions given here:

(http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedDevelopers)

However, After following the instructions, when i tried to import one of mapsforge applications (for example AdvancedMapViewer application) into my eclipse workspace, i have that red exclamation mark on the project. To find out the reason i went to the build path, it shows an x mark on this path:

> M2_REPO/org/mapsforge/mapsforge-map/0.3.1-SNAPSHOT/mapsforge-map-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Can anyone tell me how to set the M2_REPO classpath variable correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution and i am writing it down so that it may be helpful to others who faced the same problem with mapsforge project. According to this tutorial (http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedDevelopers) maven is used to build the project. Therefore, to set the classpath variable correctly i needed to know the location of my local Maven repository. In Ubuntu it's usually in user's home directory (~). it may remain there as a hidden directory named **.m2**. Therefore make sure hidden files are shown. The location of the maven repository in my case was **/home/myusername/.m2/repository**. Therefore, from Eclipse i had to go to **Window>Preferences>Java>Classpath variable** and make a **NEW** entry. Then i had to add **M2_REPO** as name and **/home/myusername/.m2/repository** as path. This results in a rebuild of the project.Now you should be able to import and run Projects from your checked out mapsforge trunk directory in your eclipse workspace without error.